# typecasting a datatype from DB to a java datatype

Tags: java, oracle, types, casting, type-conversion

I have a table in my db with following fields

```
field1 of type NUMBER(38)
other fields
```

`field2` is of type `NUMBER(38)`

Now i have some DAOS which provide me this fileld1 information in form of Object

```
 Object field1Value
```

Now i need to typecase it to a dataType.Which dataType it should be?In my case it is Integer 
But why is it getting mapped to Integer, why not Long or BigDecimal ?
Integer is 32 bits but the field is NUMBER 38 in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be casting anything. That's the role of the DAO - to effect a bridge between DB and app code.

You need to change the DAO to provide the appropriate datatype. [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) would be the best fit, because a `long` has only 64-bit precision, whereas [Oracle's number(38) datatype](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html) has 126-bit precision, and your field has no decimal part.

Comment: The thing is DAOS are already present.And it returns it in Object format.When i try to typecast it to BigInteger it gives exception saying cannot cast from Integer to BigDecimal.I know that DAOs should provide a concrete data type but its not the case here as i dont own it.Now the question is can i typecase it to integer .I thik there will be loss of precesion.I am sure that those are only integers and there are no decimal part